# Launching default application for given type of file, OS X

Tags: python, subprocess

I'm writing a python script that generates html file. Every time I run this script I'd like at the end to open default system browser for this file. It's all in OS X environment.

What python code can launch Safari/Firefox/whatever is system default html viewer and open given file? `subprocess.call` doesn't seem to do the trick.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What python code can launch
>   Safari/Firefox/whatever is system
>   default html viewer and open given
>   file?

There is a [webbrowser](http://docs.python.org/library/webbrowser.html) module in python, try this:

```
import webbrowser
webbrowser.open('file://%s' % path)
```

This will open a new tab in the default browser.
There are methods to open a new tab, new window and other options.

Comment: Yes, use the webbrowser module.  Note that it actually functions the same way as "open" on osx that simply opens the default application, whether it is the webbrowser or not.  So webbrowser.open('my.pdf') probably opens your pdf reader, not the webbrowser.  A really luxuriously great module!

Answer (score 1):

Do you know about the `open` command in Mac OS X? I think you can solve your problem by calling it from Python.

`man open` for details:

The open command opens a file (or a directory or URL), just as if you had double-clicked the
file's icon. If no application name is specified, the default application as determined via
LaunchServices is used to open the specified files.

Comment: Just use "import webbrowser" and "webbrowser.open()", on OSX it does the same as the open command from OSX itself. So opening a pdf will open it in preview and not in your browser (despite the module's name).

Answer (score 0):

> import ic
>
> ic.launchurl('file:///somefile.html')